# Using Background substract class in openCV

Tags: java, opencv, background

I want to create a program that only displays my head/body. I got openCV to work in Java with Netbeans, it recognizes my face now, but I don't know how to substract the background. I tried a couple of tutorials but none seems to address that problem?

Can someone help me or give me a hint what to look for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please clarify, if you got a videostream (multiple images) or a single image

Comment: i have a videostream

Answer (score 0):

Background substract class http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractor extract moving foreground and return a mask as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOsgEsY8UWI . If your head and body don't move and that you want to remove background, it's a pretty hard problem. Optionally, you could loop on the frame and if the pixel is outside detected face rects, you do: ‘frame.at(y, x) = Vec3b(0, 0, 0)‘ else nothing. Otherwise, you can segment on color as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRLa9h9iCQc . Best algo is segmentation on Cr, Cb channels but it won't work in every situation.